# Having Trouble Putting Strings into a List (error message)

Tags: python, html, parsing

I am trying to use the following code:

```
for x in story:
    var1 = str(x)
    var1 = var1.replace("<p>", "\n")
    var1 = var1.replace("</p>", "")
    story[x] = var1
```

To remove paragraph tags, and insert a line break, and then reinsert them into the variable. The strings are as follows:

```
Panera Bread (NASDAQ: <a class="ticker" href="/stock/pnra#NASDAQ">PNRA</a>) is down 6 percent today over expectations of food inflation of 4.5% in Q3 and 5% for Q4. In addition, Panera Will Raise Menu Prices in Q4.

PNRA recently posted second quarter 2011 earnings of $1.18 per share. Reported earnings also outpaced the prior-year quarter earnings of 85 cents per share. 

But shares were also lower ahead of the opening bell after the company reported weaker-than-expected same-store sales figures for its recent quarter late Tuesday. Its profit of $1.18 a share topped analysts' consensus call by a penny.

For the twenty-six weeks ended June 28, 2011, net income was $68 million, or $2.27 per diluted share. These results compare to net income of $53 million, or $1.67 per diluted share, for the twenty-six weeks ended June 29, 2010, and represent a 36% year-over-year increase in diluted earnings per share.
```

The error message I am getting is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\Sample Programs\Get Stuff from Pages\Pages and Stuff 0.1.py", line 34, in <module>
    story[x] = var1
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not Tag
```

Comment: @tiz answer is right, you may have to edit and post your full code, since you may be overwriting something important, my bet it `str`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`for` cycle iteratively substitutes elements of list `story` into `x` variable, while `[]` list instruction requires element index. This results into error.

```
l = ['a','b']
print l[0]
print l['a'] // type error
```

**EDIT**: I missed that story does not consists of strings. This changes can do the job:

```
story = [str(x).replace("<p>","\n").replace("<\p>","") for x in story]
```

**Note**: now `story` consists of strings, not Tags.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\Sample Programs\Get Stuff from Pages\Pages and Stuff 0.1.py", line 30, in <module>
    story = [x.replace("<p>", "\n").replace("</p>","") for x in story]
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

This is what I got when I did that

Comment: It worked, but now I can't concatenate or join all of the unicode strings inside the list - it gives me errors. Any idea how to do this?

Comment: @Andrew, I can't imagine any reason for that... All I can suggest is to create new question and publish more detailed piece of code.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to append the items to the list:

```
story.append(var1)
```

Comment: This went very slowly and froze my system.